# Apostrophes in tag names: renyōkei vs. ren'yōkei

Tags: feature-request

Right now, the [renyōkei](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reny%c5%8dkei) tag doesn't have an apostrophe.  In fact, the tag engine doesn't seem to allow us to put one there.  But [the official guidelines for romanization](http://www.mext.go.jp/b_menu/hakusho/nc/k19541209001/k19541209001.html) suggest putting one in:

> はねる音を表わすnと次にくる母音字またはyとを切り離す必要がある場合には、nの次に’を入れる。

The apostrophe is also part of [the official romanization system used by the Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/catdir/cpso/roman_japanese_revision_Mar2012.pdf), which is based on the widely used revised Hepburn system first laid out in *Kenkyusha's New Japanese-English Dictionary, third edition*.

The apostrophe makes it clear that we mean んよ /ɴyo/ and not にょ /nyo/.  I think it would be helpful if the tag engine supported this symbol.

Comment: It makes sense that the devs could add support for kanji and kana in tag names on a per-site basis that they could also add support for apostrophes in them too. Feature request seems like the way to go.

Comment: I'd gues's that thi's limitation wa's originally implemented to avoid extraneou's/erroneou's apostrophe's in tag's, to make searching/tagging easier. Unfortunately, this ha's the side effect of making `nyo` (んよ) and `nyo` (にょ) ambiguou's. Given that [apostrophe's have the potential to be misused](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/Greengrocer-S-Apostrophe.htm), we need to decide whether the ambiguity is bad enough to justify them in tag's.

Comment: FWIW, since we have unicode support for tags on this site, we can use U+02BC MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE `ʼ` in tags, which looks approximately right (though I'm not sure whether it's semantically correct).

Comment: @senshin Wouldn't it get confusing if someone typed in `ren'` and the tag disappeared?  (I haven't tested it out, so I'm not sure if that's how it would work.)

Comment: @snailboat It appears the real apostrophe is simply ignored, so using MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE `ʼ` in the main tag name, as in `renʼyōkei` and keeping `renyokei` and `renyōkei` as tag synonyms would work. But I think that's an ugly hack. Personally, I think `reɴyōkei` would be prettier, but that's not Hepburn or any other widely used romanization.

Comment: I'd like to elaborate on something @Earthliŋ just said, because I suspect many of our users are unfamiliar with this convention. In Japanese, many linguists use /Q/ for 促音, /ɴ/ for 撥音, and either /ʜ/ or /ʀ/ for 長音 in phonemic transcriptions.  (I'd like to write /Q/ small too, but unfortunately there is no small Q in Unicode.)  This way we can write ああ・こう・そう・どう as /aʜ koʜ soʜ doʜ/, write the prefix ぶっ as /buQ/, and distinguish 蟹 /kani/ from 簡易 /kaɴi/.

Comment: I'd point out that not everyone who visits this site is a linguist, and that it's less convenient/obvious for users to have to enter ɴ (as compared with n or ん) when editing/searching for a tag. I suppose that one possible solution would be to invert [what we're doing with tag description text](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1387/9212) so that an `音楽` tag began with *"on'gaku. Music etc. etc."*, since tag *descriptions* can contain apostrophes, but (A) this would require a lot of changes to tags, and (B) we run into 猫 vs. ねこ vs. ネコ - though tag synonyms would take care of the latter.

Comment: @GoBusto Yes, I agree that it would be a bad idea to put ɴ in our tags.  By the way, there's no need to write *on'gaku*; the apostrophe is used before a i u e o y following n to distinguish (for example) kani from kan'i.

Comment: @snailboat I think perhaps you misunderstood me: I'm saying that I think that it would be a *bad* idea to use ɴ in tags, because it's unconventional and less likely to be searched for than n or ん. (As for the on'gaku bit: This is a bad habit I developed from working with a romaji-to-kana conversion tool recently).

Comment: @GoBusto We both agree that it would be a bad idea :-)

Comment: @snailboat Derp, I guess I'm the one who misunderstood...

Comment: @GoBusto I'd definitely not have anyone enter ɴ to get to the right tag. But tag synonyms could take care of that. Try it for `renyōkei`: the tag is named `renyōkei`, but I doubt anyone actually enters the macron. It's found because `renyōkei` has `renyokei` as tag synonym... But we still have `renyōkei` (with macron) as main tag, because `ō` is in some sense more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't aware of that limitation.  But yes, this is definitely something that should be addressed.